# Extend Polymer Webshop

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, logic, stripe-payments

I would like to use the Polymer Shop as a boilerplate code for a real webshop.

The webshop should have the following functionality:

- Paypal/BrainTree/Stripe Integration
- Multi-Vendor/Shops
- Promotions
- Subscriptions
  ...

What is the best approach for that?

Comment: Go to https://www.webcomponents.org and look for the components you need.

Comment: propably learn polymer first? you can't simply develop eshop without any knowledge of polymer itself..